# How can I get int value from url

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

If I have a `url` like `examle/def/5/`, I tried to find `int` value from `url` by using

```
re.findall([0-9],'examle/def/5/')
```

but I get an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in 
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall return
>   _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 229, in _compile p =
>   _cache.get(cachekey) TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

How can I do this?

Comment: What error? Please share a traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 229, in _compile
    p = _cache.get(cachekey)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Please update your question with the traceback instead put in the comment.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure to import `re`.

```
>>> import re
```

Pass the first argument as string object. (Without quotes `[0-9]` a list literal equivalent to `[-9]`.)

```
>>> re.findall('[0-9]','examle/def/5/')
['5']
```

BTW, you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` to match digit (Using `r'raw string'` you don't need to escape `\`):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d','examle/def/5/')
['5']
>>> re.findall(r'\d','examle/def/567/')
['5', '6', '7']
```

If you want single numbers instead of multiple digits to be returned, use `\d+`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+','examle/def/567/')
['567']
```

Comment: ok , I got the point, actully I did not use '' in [0-9]... thanx

Comment: I am not the downvoter but I suggest that you use '\d+' to catch all the numbers not just single digits numbers.

Comment: @lcfseth, `\d+` is already in the answer code. Now added explicit explanation about `\d+`. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easy to use "regex"

While it is powerful it is dangerous as well

I dont know your exact requirement,

if you want to extract number from any where in the uri, yes the proposed solution works

```
>>> re.findall('[0-9]','examle/def/5/')
['5']
```

but I assume you want to get numbers from a "fixed place" of uri. 
if Yes, you may not desire this result

```
>>> re.findall('[0-9]','examle5/def/5/')
['5', '5']
```

I am sure you can modify regex pattern to get this done, However I will try to avoid regex, hence I would go something like this

```
>>> 'examle5/def/5/'.split('/')[-2]
'5'
```

if you want to use the extracted value then

```
try:
    int('examle5/def/5/'.split('/')[-2])   =>> will produce 5 (without quotes)
except ValueError:
    <<your code to handle when integer not present in url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a different way of doing it without regex.

```
 from string import digits
 url = 'examle/def/5/'
 nums = [i for i in list(url) if i in list(digits)]
 return "".join(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

> example/def/5/

The integer in the above url can also be retrieved through URL path converters like below.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
 path('examle/def/<int:theIntValue>/', views.showIntValue)
]
```

> Note: ***theIntValue*** variable recieve 5 as value.

Now to show/use the value, we create a function ***showIntValue()*** in the views file passing the name of variable i.e ***theIntValue***. As shown below...

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

def showIntValue(request, theIntValue):
      print(theIntValue)
```